# 7 USB devices on one computer

Tags: windows-7, usb

I do data recovery. I have a RAID issue, and I basically need to have 7 USB devices plugged into one laptop. I got them all recognized, but the issue is that windows keeps disconnecting them.. and 2 seconds later, they're back.

How can I stop my USB devices from disconnecting?

**All devices are powered.** Some are plugged into the laptop itself, some are one a hub, but each drive has its own power supply and doesn't draw any power from the laptop/hub.

Comment: What hub are you using? What power source (if any) does it have? What devices are you connecting? Do they have external power sources? There are many good solutions, but the cheapest one depends on your application. (A 7 port [hub with a beefy power supply](http://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Port-Speed-Power-Adapter/dp/B003Z4G3I6) that can supply 3A is likely best.)

Comment: See my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/330556/how-many-devices-can-be-plugged-into-a-usb-hub-and-how-is-power-distributed-amo/330570#330570 - basically, hubs have a limited amount of power they can hand out at any given time, even if powered.

Comment: None of these are the answer, I forgot to mention that every drive is powered externally. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have a power issue.  Try connecting a few USB devices through a powered USB hub with an auxiliary/external power supply.  You may even have to use *several* powered USB hubs if you run into this situation mentioned by Wikipedia:

> Some self-powered hubs do not supply enough power to drive a 500mA load on every port. For example, many seven port hubs have a 1A power supply, when in fact seven ports could draw a maximum of 7 x 0.5 = 3.5A, plus power for the hub itself. Designers assume the user will most likely connect many low power devices and only one or two requiring a full 500mA.